# Google App Engine Java - Federated Login, what to keep in Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, federated-identity

I'm building a Google App Engine for Java app using Federated login.

When a user has logged into my app using an OAuth provider I get a User object back [http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User.html].

I want to persist a link to that user in the datastore.  However, what do I use as the unique key?  Is it the getFederatedIdentity() or getUserId() ?  There is hardly any JavaDoc on either.  Obviously when a user subsequently logs into my app I want to retrieve the Object I have saved to the datastore.

I understand the federatedIdentity field, which I understand should always be populated (I only allow federated logons).  However, if that's the field to use to link my details to the logged on user, then Google leaves this empty when testing on the local server... so that wouldn't be much use.

What is the getUserId field - how does Google set it?  Will it guarantee to stay the same if the user's federated identity stays the same?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Users Java API Overview](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview.html)

> While a user is signed in to an app, the app can access the account's email address or OpenID identifier for every request the user makes to the app. The app can also access a user ID that identifies the user uniquely, even if the user changes the email address for her account.

sounds like `getUserId()` is the best choice.

Comment: ok i'll try that - i'm just curious to know how that user id field is set then... but if Google promise it will be unique and it will stay the same if the federated login is the same I'm happy.  thanks.

Comment: sounds like it's set (in the object) by the User API

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store either - you can store the User object directly in the datastore. See [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html#Properties_and_Value_Types) for a list of supported object types.

Comment: ok i can do that, but i want to store additional attributes against it (so do i end up extending it?) and i would still need to retrieve it when a user subsequently logs on, so I'd still need to retrieve the User object by a key... unless UserService.getUser returns the version in the datastore but that can't be right as what if the user changes their e-mail address.  I did see something about using e-mail addresses as the unique key for linking federated logons to data stored in my own app... but that means i need to request permissions for the user's e-mail address

Comment: @planetjones All of that is fine - what I'm saying is that you can store it as a property on your model, instead of just storing the user ID. If you need a unique, unchanging key for the key name, use the user_id.